# Large Text button in Universal Access turns itself on after reboot - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, text

I have just recently clean installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my XPS13-9333, everything seems to be working well apart from one thing that's bothering me.

The text on the menu bar or the text in the folders often becomes large after I restarted the laptop. It took me a while to work out that this is because the Large Text option in Universal Access under system settings is turning itself on. Turn it off manually helps occasionally, but every now and then after rebooting the text will again become large.

Is there anyway I can fix this, I would appreciate it a lot? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem on a Lenovo X1 2nd Generation (14" with 2560x1440px) and *"fixed"* it by adding the following file to *~/.config/autostart/* :

*largetextfix.desktop*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=largetextfix
Exec=dconf reset /com/canonical/unity/interface/text-scale-factor
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

Maybe that'll do for you as well.

sorry... the other (previous) solution turned out to be somehow unstable as well...

Comment: Only just seen this, will try it out and see if it works, thanks a lot!